# How do you calculate $\mathcal P(A) \times \mathcal P(B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do you calculate $\mathcal P(A) \times \mathcal P(B)$?

Let's say we have this example:
$A=\{2\}$
$B=\{7\}$
Then this should be the case:
$\mathcal P(A) \times \mathcal P(B)$

$\mathcal P(A)=\{ \emptyset , \{2\} \}$
$\mathcal P(B)=\{ \emptyset , \{7\} \}$
How do you continue from here?

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you know how to define the product of two sets?  There's nothing special about power sets in this regard...

Comment: As lulu said, power sets are like any other set. The product of them is the set of ordered pairs where the first element comes from P(A) and the second one comes from P(B).

Comment: Your example makes sense, but I don't grasp where you want to go regarding "continue from here." We can give the size (cardinality) of the product, and expand on the definition for general $A, B$.  I don't know what more you would like as a response.

Comment: @hardmath I just want to understand these types of problems since I'm learning set theory currently and my book doesn't have examples that I understand. I want to know how to solve it and get the cardinality and the thought process behind it.

Comment: @lulu Yes I understand that know, but how do you do that process when it comes to power sets times another power set?

Comment: Again, power sets are just sets.  You take their product exactly the same way you would take the product of any two sets.

Comment: @lulu Can you please provide an example as an answer because I really want to understand these kinds of problems correctly before I move on with more advanced topics in set theory.

Comment: If your two sets are $S_1=\{a,b\}$ and $S_2=\{x,y\}$ then $S_1\times S_2$ has four elements, namely $(a,x), (a,y), (b,x), (b,y)$

Comment: Thanks for answering. But what happens with the empty set?

Comment: It seems this might have been an exercise to appreciate the [Kuratowski ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition), given "I'm learning set theory currently".

Comment: that's just another element of your set.  In what I wrote, $x$ could be the empty set, for example.